# How can I ensure my self-answered question isn't too broad?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, self-answer

I am almost ready to post a question that I am self answering and I want to make sure that I do it perfectly the first time because of the amount of effort/research I put into the answer.

It's a bit harder to put "research" into the question, but I've tried:

1. It has an excerpt (with a link) from another highly voted post that explains the subject.
2. I have a note at the bottom that should hopefully prevent backlash from audits. Here's the wording I'm using:

   > <sup><sub>There are sources that cover this, but I didn't particularly like them. I wanted a page for reference, so I have formulated my own answer (it's not very long either). I welcome any suggestions for improving my question or answer. Feel free to add your own answer, too.</sub></sup>
3. I have looked up posts on the Metas about self-answering; it was more discouraging than helpful. I want to get some feedback (and encouragement) for my situation specifically.

There are a few things that worry me about the question:

1. It can be answered with a *little* less or a *whole lot* more than what I have written, depending on the level of abstraction. There are entire books that bring up the subject in detail.
2. The answer's in the documentation. (It's really long and contains irrelevant details, but I link to it in my answer.)
3. I don't want make anything community wiki. I put too much effort into it to want CW.
4. It could be considered controversial. It's a bit hard to explain, but I am using several "trigger phrases" that make people jump to conclusions.

---

My main concern is that people will misunderstand what my question is, and think it's either asking "gimme teh codez" (where "teh codez" could be several thousand lines), or for hundreds if not thousands of lines from the documentation.

The fact I was able to write an answer in less than two pages (some of which is from formatting titles and lists) should mean that it's not too broad if we assume that my answer is good and thorough.

Does the possibility that an answer *could* be book length prevent me from posting the question with a reasonably sized answer?

Comment: consider [case study approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_method) - that is, post a narrower question that covers particular typical case of your topic and follow it with the answer that starts with directly addressing that narrower case and ends with general analysis

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure how that would work. My answer breaks down the problem pretty well already. The subject of my question is the lexical rules of HTML, which doesn't have a good "typical case".

Comment: Sounds like you should be posting the content on a blog, it sounds like it's not suited for SO and you know it.

Comment: @Servy Maybe, but you can't close things as duplicates of someone's blog. My question is in fact programming related.

Comment: @Laurel Neither of those things make the question appropriate for Stack Overflow.  The fact that you can't close questions as duplicates of it doesn't make your question sufficiently narrow, and there are *lots* of programming questions that don't belong on SO, such as those that are Too Broad, like yours appears to be.

Comment: @Servy What makes my question too broad?

Comment: @Laurel Well, for starters, you've specifically said that entire books have been written about this question, which is literally the textbook example given of a question that's Too Broad.

Comment: @Servy Many of the popular questions on SO could be answered with entire books. Take this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) . Now look at this [book](http://www.crsr.net/files/floating_point_math.pdf) and tell why that question isn't too broad.

Comment: @Laurel That question *is* too broad, as evidenced by the fact that it's full of "answers" that don't actually provide a [complete] answer to the question, and many that just end up linking elsewhere for an actual answer to the question (precisely because it's too broad of a question to answer in an SO answer).

Comment: @Servy But it's possible to delve into that much detail with any subject, really. If a good, relevant, complete, succinct answer exists *can the question be too broad?* I guess I don't understand why the close reason exists.

Comment: No, it's *not* possible to delve into that much detail on any subject *and have all of that content be on topic to answering the question*.  A good question will focus the topic to the point that if someone tried writing a book as an answer the vast majority of that content would be off topic to the question.  `If a good, relevant, complete, succinct answer exists [...]`  You have not demonstrated that your question would have a good, relevant, *complete*, *succinct*, answer.  Everything you've described about your question indicates it's answers would fail to meet both of the last two points.

Comment: @Servy You are correct in saying my answer could be more succinct. The question is more narrow than what my answer would indicate. I might be exaggerating when I say that there are books written entirely on the subject.

Comment: @Laurel So you're arguing that the question isn't too broad, the answer is just largely off topic for the question, and isn't a good answer?

Comment: @Servy I address the topic completely, but give some broader information.

Comment: @Laurel So that's a yes then, you're filling the answer with lots of off topic information?  This brings us full circle to my first comment.  It sounds like you have a blog post, not an SO answer, and your struggles in trying to post it as an SO post is because it's no suited to being an SO post.

Comment: @Servy I'm more concerned about my question. It's not very helpful that you keep on insisting that I make a blog, could you please focus on how I could improve things for SO?

Comment: @Laurel You're trying to post something that isn't appropriate for the site.  It's like someone coming here and asking how they need to edit their Cooking question to make it appropriate for SO. You're trying to put a blog post onto an SO question, and SO isn't suited for such content.

Comment: @Servy Do you disagree with gnat's suggestion?  `post a narrower question that covers particular typical case of your topic and follow it with the answer that starts with directly addressing that narrower case and ends with general analysis`

Comment: @Laurel It's a matter of scale.  Adding a paragraph or so to mention a few important points would be fine, going into significant depth, as it sounds like you're trying to do, such that majority of the post is no longer actually answering the question would be a problem.

Comment: @Servy Some of the length comes from defining terms, justifying my notation, and explaining that my answer isn't applicable to XHTML/XML. That is about 25% of the length of the post. The other 75% *could* be shrunk down to a few lines if I decided to remove all the plain English descriptions.